# finding & returning specific line from files in python with tkinter

Tags: python, file, output

i am a newbie in python, and i am trying to code a comparison tool and i used tkinter in python 2.7. my gui seems to work fine, but i cannot find the line containing the 'key' to return (even if i use correct key). hoping for your help.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import os
import tkFont

result = ""
key = ""

def clear():
    var4.set("Results...")
    entry.set("")

def process():
    key = entered.get()
    if len(key) == 5 or len(key) == 6:
        result = look_up()
        var4.set(result)
    else:
        result = 'Invalid Entry, please enter 5-6 alphanumeric characters... !'
        var4.set(result)

def look_up():
    file = "compared.txt"
    fh = open(file, 'r')
    key = pdbCode.get()
    lines = fh.readlines() 
    for line in lines:
        #just trying to return a single line first to check
        if line.strip().startswith(key):
            #a, b, c, d = line.split("::")  
            #print "For item     : " + str(a)
            #print "description1 : " + str(b)
            #print "description2 : " + str(c)
            #print "value        : " + str(c) 
            return line
        else:
            return "Code not in file..."

root = Tk()
root.title('Comparisson')
root.geometry('550x550+200+200')

entry = StringVar()
entered = Entry(root,textvariable = entry, width = 15)
entered.pack()


button1 = Button(root, text='COMPARE', width = 10, pady = 5, command = process)
button1.pack()

var4 = StringVar()
label4 = Label( root, textvariable=var4, pady = 45)
var4.set("Result here...")
label4.pack()

button2 = Button(root, text='CLEAR ALL', width = 10, command = clear)
button2.pack()

button3 = Button(root, text='QUIT', width = 10, command = root.destroy)
button3.pack()

root.resizable(0, 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This has been resolved!

Comment: how about sharing what you did to resolve the problem, so others can learn from you? It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.